# Unit testing objects with nested properties

Tags: java, unit-testing, jaxb

I would like to know what is the best approach in order to unit test objects with nested properties.

This is the structure I'm using. `ContainerType` is a sort of wrapper object. It contains two `String` properties and an `HolderList` property. `HolderList` is an object that contains a list of `Holder`s and so on. The model is like this one because I'm using JAXB in order to generate an XML output.

```
public class Container
{
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private HolderList holderList;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public HolderList getHolderList() {
        return holderList;
    }

    public void setHolderList(HolderList holderList) {
        this.holderList = holderList;
    }

    public static class HolderList
    {
        private List<Holder> holders;

        public List<Holder> getHolders() {
            return holders;
        }

        public void setHolders(List<Holder> holders) {
            this.holders = holders;
        }
    }
    public static class Holder
    {
        private String code;
        private GroupList groupList;

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public GroupList getGroupList() {
            return groupList;
        }

        public void setGroupList(GroupList groupList) {
            this.groupList = groupList;
        }
    }
    public static class GroupList
    {
        private List<Group> groups;

        public List<Group> getGroups() {
            return groups;
        }

        public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
            this.groups = groups;
        }
    }
    public static class Group
    {
        private String code;
        private TitleList titleList;

        public TitleList getTitleList() {
            return titleList;
        }

        public void setTitleList(TitleList titleList) {
            this.titleList = titleList;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
    }
    public static class TitleList
    {
        private List<Title> titles;

        public List<Title> getTitles() {
            return titles;
        }

        public void setTitles(List<Title> titles) {
            this.titles = titles;
        }
    }
    public static class Title
    {
        private String code;
        private String description;

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

My approach would be like this, but I think unit tests will become unreadable. In addition this pattern is not developer friendly.

```
Container container = operation.getContainer(request);
assertNotNull(container);
assertEquals("0", container.getOutcomeCode());
assertEquals(1, container.getHolderList().getHolders().size());
assertEquals("123456", container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getCode());
assertEquals(2, container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getGroupList().getGroups().size());
assertEquals("123456", container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getGroupList().getGroups().get(0).getCode());
assertEquals(1, container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getGroupList().getGroups().get(0).getTitleList().getTitles().size());
assertEquals("123456", container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getGroupList().getGroups().get(1).getCode());
assertEquals(7, container.getHolderList().getHolders().get(0).getGroupList().getGroups().get(1).getTitleList().getTitles().size());
// additional asserts here
```

Do you suggest any other approach?

**Update**

Within `operation.getContainer` I'm creating a `ContainerType` with all nested its nested properties. The marshalling with JAXB is done after this step. So, I would like to test this method in order to verify the method returns the expected object. Does this test make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with `HolderList` + `Holder` definitions is indeed extremely hard to maintain.

There is no need to create intermediate wrapper objects like `HolderList`, because JAXB supports annotations and the same output can be achieved by using:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Container {

  private String code;
  private String description;

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "holderList")
  private List<Holder> holders;

}
```

The three `*List` classes are thus removed from the original code.

I can also suggest to extract all the nested classes (`Holder`, `Group`, `Title`) to their dedicated files: this simplifies the structure, makes it easier to navigate and is simply cleaner.

*Update*:

The arguments to `assertEquals` can be refactored with shortcut methods:

```
private static Holder getFirstHolder(Container container) {
  return container.getHolders().get(0);
}

// and
assertEquals("123456", getFirstHolder(container).getCode());
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yep, it will definitely help my structure and my uni tests as well. Do you have any suggestion for the unit-test part?

Comment: Concerning the unit tests part, it really depends on what you want to test. Usually, tests on POJOs that contain only getters/setters do not add much value. I updated the answer with a short idea about the assertions.

Comment: Thanks. The think I'm testing here is `operation.getContainer()`.

Comment: Within `operation.getContainer` I'm creating a `ContainerType` with all its nested properties. The marshalling with JAXB is done after this step. So, I would like to test this method in order to verify the method returns the expected object. Does this test make sense? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sure, it _is_ necessary to test the contents of the result returned by `operation.getContainer`.